# Create a list of tuples with the first position fixed

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a list of tuples with two elements keeping the first item always fixed. This is the code I'm using to achieve this, but it is not working as expected.

```
def grouper(n, iterable):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip(*args)

df_rel_inward['list_of_tuples'] = ''

for i in range(0,len(df_rel_inward['tuple']), 1):
    df_rel_inward['list_of_tuples'][i] = tuple(grouper(2, df_rel_inward['tuple'][i]))

df_rel_inward
```

The output is `((1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6))`

I have no idea on how to fix the first element, so the output can be `((1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6))`

Can you, please, advise?

Comment: So you want a tuple list that consists of (1,X) where X is [x,y]? If that's the case you are thinking WAY to complicated. Try to start from scratch, use list comprehension cast the list to a tuple and you have a one liner.

Comment: How about `[(1, x) for x in df_rel_inward['tuple']]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension

```
t = tuple((1,i) for i in range(1,7))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful:

```
df_rel_inward = []
for i in range(1, 10):
    df_rel_inward.append((1,i))
print(tuple(df_rel_inward))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an indexing problem. When you create a tuple, you index it with a single `[]` operator, like this:

```
a = (1, 2)
a[0] == 1
a[1] == 2
```

But, you have a *list* of *tuples*. Therefore, you have two indexes, using two `[]` operators:

```
a = [(1, 2), (3, 4)]
a[0] == (1, 2)
a[0][0] == 1
a[0][1] == 2
a[1][0] == 3
a[1][1] == 4
```

You'll need to have your first index fixed and the second one iterating.